# Text to columns based on unique list and multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I have a set of data with multiple columns.  I'm trying to transfer the data from columns to rows, but only for the unique members.

For instance, I would like the "Hours Worked" to populate under the correct month in the rows to the right based on unique "SSN"

I've tried =IF($P2=$C2,HLOOKUP(Q$1,$H:$H,MATCH(Q$1,$H:$H,0),FALSE),"")
Index/Match, etc but can't figure it out.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13jJJ0GXb6hFW7YEyyqrCn8cfotUeFurtm0U1EFj_kPY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why not just use a Pivot Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula in cell `F2` and copy it over:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($E2=$A$2:$A$13),--(F$1=$C$2:$C$13),$B$2:$B$13)
```

The result of `($E2=$A$2:$A$13)` is an array containing trues and falses, depending on whether the ID in column E is equal to the ID in column A. `(F$1=$C$2:$C$13)`does the same thing for the date. By adding `--` in front of these arrays, we convert the trues and falses to ones and zeros, respectively. The third array contains the hours worked in each month. These three arrays are then multiplied (and summed up in case there were several entries for one ID in one month).

Comment: Brilliant!  I have no idea what is happening, but it works!

Comment: I added some explanations above, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks!  It works, and I understand it, but i had too large of a range and it killed my memory so I used the pivottable approach instead/